Question on Correspondence Between Higher Rank Bundles on $\mathbb{P}^2$ and Irreducible Representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$
I have been studying the theory of highest weights and irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ , following Fulton-Harris' book. I understand how the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem allows us to construct line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^2$ corresponding to irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$.
However, I am curious about whether it is possible to establish a similar correspondence between simple vector bundles of higher rank on $\mathbb{P}^2$ and irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$. If this correspondence exists, I would like to understand how it plays out. Specifically, how do these higher rank bundles arise in relation to the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$?
